# paste on top of the row instead of the bottom row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

at the moment I have a sheet that has a script that is time triggered, the script at the end of the day will copy sheets at the bottom of the target sheet, everytime I am trying to do targetSheet.getrange(1,1) + 1; it's not  converting range to int. can someone please help?

```
   function copyData() {
  
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('copiedPausingSheet');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();


  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('collectivePausingData');
  let lastrowCount = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(lastrowCount,1, rowCount,columnCount);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Comment: `targetSheet.getRange(1,1) + 1` has no mean there is no operator `+` that adds one to a range.  So you have to depend upon the methods of Class Range.  For example `targetSheet.getRange(1,1).offset(0,1).getValue()` is the same thing as `targetSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue()`

Comment: wouldnt that be a static coordinates though? that means it wont push the last value below , it'd just replace it? @cooper

Comment: I don't understand you comment

Comment: if we set definitely value to the targetrange for example targetSheet.getRange(1,1) then if the script run it will just replace the current value of cell instead of pasting on top of the cells that has value? @Cooper as mentioned at the question, the script that I have runs every 2am and copy all the data of the sourcesheet to the  bottom of the targetsheet

Comment: use  insertRows(startposition, howmanyrows) if you want to insert 5 rows in the top of the sheet, .insertRows(1,5).    If your value length is 10,  get the value.length then .insertRows(1,value.length).   Then sheet.getRange(1,1,value.length,value[0].length).setValues(value).  That would do the work.

Comment: I need to copy all the data from the sourcesheet to the top of the targetsheet, not add rows. unfortunately, I figured out how to do it the other way around where the sourcesheets data will be pasted at the last empty row of the targetsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you mean? Paste values on the top of the sheet.

```
function copyData() {
  
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('copiedPausingSheet');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();


  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('collectivePausingData');
  targetSheet.insertRows(1,sourceValues.length);
  
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceValues.length,sourceValues[0].length);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Comment: this is perfecT!

Comment: @jovepascual, [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
function copyDataOnTop() {

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('copiedPausingSheet');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('collectivePausingData');
  var targetValues = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var allValues = [...sourceValues, ...targetValues];
  
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,allValues.length,allValues[0].length);
  targetRange.setValues(allValues);
}
```

Comment: almost, but this does the same thing that my code does, pasting it at the bottom, I need it to paste at the top?

Comment: It pastes all rows from the source sheet to the top of the target sheet.